# Cronjob etiquette?

Tags: cron, administration

I am a student at a relatively small university. I wrote a script that sends me an email when a math newsletter comes out, so I can get a head-start on the problem of the week.

I plan to run it as a cronjob, so that it can poll the newsletter website every five minutes. Because my laptop is often not connect to the internet, or asleep, I plan to run it on one of the university's servers.

Should I alert the system administrators to the fact that I am running this cronjob? Is there any etiquette in regards to running cronjobs?

Comment: Ideally, the newsletter / website would have an RSS (or atom/etc) feed, so that you don't have to "poll", but can rather "subscribe" to updates. (Look for a rss or atom icon on their site.) In the absence of a good host, clients can't be faulted for lapses in etiquette. (It's nice of you to ask, though.)

Comment: @michael_n And how would you get the feed updates? You'd still have to poll them (or let some service do it for you). In the end a feed is really just an alternative representation. It doesn't include or offer some kind of push notification.

Comment: @Mario RSS is designed exactly for what is being asked. One should at least check to see if the option is available. (And, we're talking about the impact on the server, not effort on the client. Nonetheless, an aggregator/reader is a lot simpler to use than setting up a cronjob to send out email.) For a server, polling via http (or push notifications) does not scale. To call it "an alternative representation" is an understatement; RSS/ATOM allows for alternate, scalable architectures. Changes can be published to a syndication server; and clients can easily monitor using readers (like email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal etiquette regarding use of cron.  Every system is different and may have its own policies, of which you may have been notified when getting access.  It's worth noting that system administrators have the capability to enable/disable crontab for users, so, if you have access to crontab then arguably this is a tacit approval.  That said, checking every five minutes seems excessive.  Is this really the only way to be notified of a published document?  What if everyone wanted to do that?

You'd be better off volunteering to set up an email distribution list or other subscription based service to improve this for everyone.

Comment: If you tried doing this on any well-maintained server (e.g., consider google.com), you'll get a captcha or simply be blocked from access for crossing some unknown, invisible line. (If you've ever restored your browser with 50+ tabs open with google queries, you know what I mean.)